# JDBC Connection to remote server using IP Address

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ip-address

I've two laptops in same wifi network.

Laptop A has ip address 192.168.1.102
I've installed Oracle Database on Laptop A.

I want to access the database from Laptop B.

1st I tried ping command,

[image]

Then I tried to access database installed on Laptop A from Laptop B using following Code,

```
package test.remote.server;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestRemoteServer
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            String IPAddress="192.168.1.102";

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            System.out.println("Class Found !");

            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+IPAddress+":1521:XE","system","manager");
            System.out.println("Connection Established !");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If I run this code from Laptop A (where database is installed) then output is

```
Class Found !
Connection Established !
```

When I run same code on Laptop B, I get Error as follow

```
Class found !
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)   at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at test.remote.server.TestRemoteServer.main(TestRemoteServer.java:20)
```

How can I access database installed on laptop A from laptop B?

Comment: Open port 1521 in the firewall(s).

Comment: You can check to see if that 1521 port is open to Laptop B by using a tool like `netcat` or similar on laptop B.

Comment: After opening the port 1521 on Laptop B, it worked !